# GRE Sentence Completion -2

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, logic, gre

> It comes as no surprise that societies have codes of behavior; the character of the codes, on the other hand, can often be _________ .

A) predictable

B) unexpected

C) admirable

D) explicit

E) confusing

**Choice B-unexpected** is correct, but I think **choice E** can also be right. Isn't it?

Comment: 'on the other hand' should introduce a direct contrast. 'unexpected' is the best counterpart to 'surprise'. 'confusing' is not right because it is somewhat on the same side as 'surprising' in this context.

Comment: Yes but surprising has a positive connotation whereas confusing has a negative.

Comment: Manish: good point, and that's exactly the kind of nuances it is good to make explicit when answering these kinds of questions. But the _closer_ opposite of 'no surprise' is 'unexpected' rather than just 'negative' ('confusing' has too many other meanings beyond negative which are not related to the positive of 'no surprise'). So 'no surprise' is perfect but 'confusing' isn't. If 'unexpected' weren't a choice, 'confusing' might be the best of the remaining, but that still doesn't make it good; it just seems irrelevant (like the others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first part, there is `It comes as no surprise`. In the second part, they use `on the other hand` which imho means that they are looking for a word with an opposite meaning - something like "surprising". Therefore, I would choose B - `unexpected`.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "on the other hand" implies a contrast with an omitted "on the one hand" in the first clause. In this example the only choice offered which contrasts with any term in the first clause is "unexpected", which contrasts with "no surprise".